# How to effectively force close file if sheet is deleted?

Tags: excel

I have this file with 62 sheets and I ideally would want to prevent those sheets from being deleted for whichever uses this file. Protecting the workbook or its structure is not an option unfortunately, so I came up with a solution that goes like this:
On one of the cells I count the number of sheets (62 in this case) and I'll put this code on "thisworkbook":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If sheet24.range("B14"). Value < 62 then
Msgbox("Error. File will be closed")
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End if
End sub
```

Well.. It works, but the only problem is after deleting a sheet, I'll have to select a cell to update the code and force close...meaning that if someone saves the file in between deleting sheet and selecting a cell, it is still possible.
How could I improve the code? (Taking in consideration this is a fairly old computer.)

Comment: Maybe the `sheetchange` event for the workbook? Edit: there's even a `sheetbeforedelete` event.

Comment: Without being able to protect the workbook, there really isn't a way to prevent a user from deleting a worksheet.  Even with VBA, all a user needs to do is disable macros and then none of your code matters.

Comment: Please pay attention to the description of tags you select. `forceclose` is a specific Android-related tag and has absolutely nothing to do with Excel, so I've removed it from your post. Tags have specific meanings here, and it's inappropriate just to randomly grab those that contain familiar sounding words or phrases. Read the description before using it, and if you're not certain it applies then don't include it; if it's needed, someone here can add it for you. Thanks.

Comment: with `beforedelete` you could create a copy (before or after the sheet to delete) rename the old sheet (to an unused string) then change name of the copy to the old name and replace the unused string in all formulas to the old name... then after deleting, it looks like nothing happend... theoretically ;D